# Ubuntu 12.04 grub error on sony vaio z

Tags: vaio

I am new Linux user and I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04.2 amd64 on my sony vaio z. However, there is an error at the end of the installation process in which the boot loader was not located. (using USB for the installation)

Thanks

Comment: We need to know what the exact error is.

Answer (score 0):

It has problems with Raid. Basicly you can setup new hardware RAID0 via BIOS and you should install grub to something like: /dev/mapper/YOUR_RAID_NAMEp1

Last two simbols mean that it will be install in first partition.

You can create soft RAID. More details in [this](http://forum.notebookreview.com/sony/702661-clean-install-ubuntu-12-10-sony-vaio-z-svz-2012-how.html#post9019585) manual.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.